# How to scrape texts in order / merge texts?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to merge text element in `rlg-item__paint` class with text element in `rlg-trade__itemshas` class, like so:

```
url = "https://rocket-league.com/trade/465ec00f-2f5c-48e2-831e-2e294683ad56"
response = requests.get(f"{url}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for has in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'rlg-trade__itemshas'}):
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'rlg-item-links'}):
        div.extract()
    for color in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'rlg-item__paint'}):
        color.replaceWith('\n', color)
    items = (has.get_text(f"\n"' ', strip=True))
    print(items)
```

but it doesn't work, output:

```
Magma
Pink
Light Show
Cristiano
Anodized Pearl
```

`Pink` text element from `rlg-item__paint` class, I want to merge it like this:

```
Magma
Pink Light Show
Cristiano
Anodized Pearl
```

so I want to merge it in bottom row  of text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

If pattern is always the same you could select your element more specific, extract text with `.stripped_strings` and slice the `<a>` texts:

```
for e in soup.select('.rlg-trade__itemshas .--hover'):
    print(' '.join(list(e.stripped_strings)[:-2]))
```

or you could use `.decompose()` to get rid of the links:

```
for e in soup.select('.rlg-trade__itemshas .--hover'):
    e.select_one('.rlg-item-links').decompose()
    print(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://rocket-league.com/trade/465ec00f-2f5c-48e2-831e-2e294683ad56"
response = requests.get(f"{url}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for e in soup.select('.rlg-trade__itemshas .--hover'):
    print(' '.join(list(e.stripped_strings)[:-2]))
```

##### Output

```
Magma
Pink Light Show
Cristiano
Anodized Pearl
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but all elements appear in output, when I print it to the .txt file, it only prints last element.

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow - Cause writing something to text file is out of question scope and to keep ist clear this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus.

Comment: @yusufkuşçu you have to keep all items on list and later use `for`-loop to write items from list. OR you have to write it directly inside for-loop which you use to search element. And if you use `open()` `close()` inside loop then remember to run in `append mode` instead or `write mode` - `open(..., "a")`